# Nothing is happening when i press space in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making my first unity project. I wanted to add jumps but nothing happens when I press space. I'm using C#. I checked and inputs should be fine. Could anyone please help?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pmovr : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 jump;
    public float jumpForce = 20.0f;
    public bool isGrounded;
    Rigidbody rb;   
    public CharacterController pmove;
    public float speed = 12f;
    public float grav = -9.81f;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    void Start(){
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    void OnCollisionStay()
        {
        isGrounded = true;
        }
    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        pmove.Move(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        velocity.y += grav * Time.deltaTime;
        pmove.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);      
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded){
            rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your script and I faced the following problems:

- CharacterController script is builded to work without rigidbodies, so
  forces applied to it won't affect.
- CharacterController has it's own colliders, so adding it more (I
  don't know if you do that, but just covering possibilities) can cause
  problems to check if it's ground or not.

My recommendation is to remove your CharacterController script and keep coding his behaviour. If you achieve to do the jump, move will be easy for you!

*Anyways and as advice, try to debug separately your variables. 
When you press space, print the value of "isGrounded" if it is true, check the state of the rb, etc.*

Comment: now nothing works, I cant move at all after removing and adding character controller.

Comment: did you code a way to move as my solution says? or you're calling Move method even if you remove your character Controller?

Comment: to be honest I have no idea how to do it without force. But I think that that is indeed the problem.

Comment: Don't worry, everyone has been on your place. Let me recommend you this channel, it's nice for beginers, and this concrete video talks about your case, movement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the tips. I followed some tutorials, so it jumps now, but it sadly falls extremely fast.